# Property of interface implemented by c# class not accessible from c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I'm trying to implement a native interface in C++/CLI, to a class developed in c#. I'm using VS2013.

Here's a simplified version of the C# class:

```
namespace ManagedTypes
{
    public static class CaptureFile
    {
        public static IPacketList GetPackets() { new PacketList(); }
    }
}
```

Here's the definition of the IPacketList interface:

```
namespace ManagedTypes
{
    public interface IPacketList: IReadOnlyList<IPacket>
    {
    }
}
```

Just to be thorough, `IReadOnlyList<T>` (in mscorlib) is declared as:

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
}
```

and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (also is mscrolib) as

```
public interface IReadOnlyCollection<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    int Count { get; }
}
```

So, from C#, I can do something like:

```
var n = CaptureFile.GetPackets().Count;
```

But if I try to do something similar from C++:

```
auto n = CaptureFile::GetPackets()->Count;
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MixedMode, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "C:\Hg\DP1000-DEV\src\Spikes\MixedModeSample\ManagedTypes\bin\Debug\ManagedTypes.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
1>  MixedModeApi.cpp
1>MixedModeApi.cpp(9): error C2039: 'Count' : is not a member of 'ManagedTypes::IPacketList'
1>          c:\hg\dp1000-dev\src\spikes\mixedmodesample\managedtypes\bin\debug\managedtypes.dll : see declaration of 'ManagedTypes::IPacketList'
1>MixedModeApi.cpp(10): error C3536: 'n': cannot be used before it is initialized
2>------ Build started: Project: NativeApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Hg\DP1000-DEV\src\Spikes\MixedModeSample\Debug\MixedMode.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the error message from the Output window in Visual Studio? Compilation errors are frequently multiple lines long, and more informative than the error list.

Comment: Updated the post with the complete content of the output window

Comment: You are ignoring the first warning.  IReadOnlyList is a .NET 4.5 type but you are targeting 4.0

Comment: Right @HansPassant! Can you answer the question so that I can mark it as such? And thanks @DavidYaw for your valuable input.